# Sending an email to a user after submitting an enquiry

Tags: node.js, reactjs, nodemailer

I'm trying to find a way to set up a contact us form, when a user is submitting an enquiry I should receive an email, also the user should receive an email telling that the enquiry reached us, I figured out that I should use nodemailer to send mails, now the first step is done which I receive an email whenever the user submitted an enquiry, the question is how can I send him an email after submitting the enquiry? excuse my bad English

**`Nodemailer setup`**

```
//email from the contact form using the nodemailer
router.post('/send', async(req, res) => {
  console.log(req.body);
  const transporter = nodemailer.createTransport({
      service: 'gmail',
      auth: {
          user: process.env.EMAIL_USERNAME, //email resposible for sending message
          pass: process.env.EMAIL_PASSWORD
      }
  });
  const mailoptions = {
      from: process.env.FROM_EMAIL,
      to: process.env.EMAIL_USERNAME, //email that recives the message
      subject: 'New Enquiry',
      html: `<html><body><p>Name: ${req.body.name}</p><p> Email: ${req.body.email}</p><p>message: ${req.body.content}</p></body></html>`
  }
  transporter.sendMail(mailoptions, (err, info) => {
      if (err) {
          console.log('error');
          res.send('message not sent'); //when its not ent
      } else {
          console.log('message sent' + info.response);
          res.send('sent'); //when sent
      }
  })

});

module.exports = router;
```

Answer (score 0):

So I tried some codes and code worked for me, it's sending to the admin and the client, hope it helps

```
router.post('/send', async(req, res, next) => {
  console.log(req.body);
  if (!req.body.name) {
    return next(createError(400, "ERROR MESSAGE HERE"));
  } else if (!req.body.email) {
    return next(createError(400, "ERROR MESSAGE HERE"));
  } else if (!req.body.email || !isEmail(req.body.email)) {
    return next(createError(400, "ERROR MESSAGE HERE"));
  } else if (!req.body.content) {
    return next(createError(400, "ERROR MESSAGE HERE"));
  } 

  const transporter = nodemailer.createTransport({
      service: 'gmail',
      auth: {
          user: process.env.EMAIL_USERNAME, //email resposible for sending message
          pass: process.env.EMAIL_PASSWORD
      }
  });

  const mailOptionsAdmin = {
      from: process.env.FROM_EMAIL,
      to: process.env.EMAIL_USERNAME, //email that recives the message
      subject: 'New Enquiry',
      html: `<html><body><p>Name: ${req.body.name}</p><p> Email: ${req.body.email}</p><p>message: ${req.body.content}</p></body></html>`
  }

  const mailOptionsClient = {
    from: process.env.FROM_EMAIL,
    to: req.body.email, //email that recives the message
    subject: 'Recivied',
    html: `<html><body><p>message: We recived your enquiry</p></body></html>`
}

  transporter.sendMail(mailOptionsAdmin, (err, info) => {
    if (err) {
          console.log('error');
          res.send('message not sent'); //when its not ent
      } else {
          console.log('message sent' + info.response);
          res.send('sent'); //when sent
          transporter.sendMail(mailOptionsClient)

      }
  })

});
```